# Have a relationship between one table with one primary key and another with two primary keys?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm asking about this generally, but I'll give an example for illustration purposes.

Table1 has the following columns:

```
ID (Pk)
Order_Desc
Order_DT
```

Table2 has the following columns:

```
ID (PK)
Product_Code (PK)
Product_Desc
```

Is it possible for me to have relationship between Table1 and Table2. If so, how would you do this in SQL without you running into an error? Would you be able to create a relationship if the Product Code or ID was not a primary key? Instead, it was a foreign key?

Comment: Your `table2` does **not** have two primary keys - it has **ONE** primary key made up from 2 columns. Any relational table ***NEVER*** has more than one primary key - it's just not possible at all. Any FK relationship must now include **all** the columns that the PK of the referenced table has  - so any FK to `Table2` **must include* both `ID` and `Product_Code`

Comment: Gotcha, basically, you need ID and Product_Code to be present in both tables, Table1 and Table2. If the composite primary key was ID and Product Code, right?

Comment: Yes - you can **only** reference the **whole (primary) key** - not parts of it. It's an all-or-nothing - no reference, or then you **must include** all columns in the referenced table's primary key in your foreign key

Comment: This make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `table2` does not have **two** primary keys - it has **ONE** primary key made up from 2 columns. Any relational table **NEVER** has more than one primary key - it's just not possible at all.

Any FK relationship to that table must include **all the** columns that the PK of the referenced table has - so any FK to `Table2` **must include** both `ID` and `Product_Code`.

It's an all or nothing proposition - either your foreign key includes **all** columns of the referenced tables primary key - or you cannot establish a FK-relationship.